# VueJs - Element Ui - Table same prop different filters

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm building a table with a set of data.

```
{
  date: '2016-05-03',
  name: 'Tom'        
  address: 'No. 189, Grove St, Los Angeles',
  tag: 'Home'
}
```

The prop `date` is going to be used to create two columns in my table `date` and `day`.

```
  getDay(row, column) {
    return row.date.slice(8,10);
  },
```

I would like to be able to filter independently the column `date` and `day`. Or the filter method relies on the `prop` of the table.

```
filterTag(value, row) {
    return row.tag === value;
  },
  filterDay(value, row) {
    return row.date === value;
  }
```

What would be the best solution in such a situation ?

I would like to not duplicate my data `date` by creating a new key `day` since it is the same data but just filtered.

Is there any other solution or impossible to do without creating a new key `day`

https://jsfiddle.net/o56yveqq/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a computed value to get the `tableData` in the format you want.

```
computed:{
    dataWithDay(){
        return this.tableData.map(d => {
            return {
            ...d,
            day: d.date.slice(8,10)
          }
        })
    }
},
```

Then in your template, use the computed value as your data instead of `tableData`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What would you say it is the best/fastest approach. Use a computed property as you proposed, so the client has to modify and build the data, or to do the same on the `server side` ?

Comment: @Leo Server side would technically be faster, but I'm not sure it would be noticeable. Best is a matter of opinion. The day value is truly only necessary client side you could make an argument the client should manage it, but I could go both ways.